# Netty 4 handle channel events

Tags: java, events, netty

In Netty 3 I can handle open/close events with ChannelUpstreamHandler, like

```java
pipeline.addLast("channelGroupHandler", new SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler() {
  public void channelOpen(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) {
    ...
  }

  public void channelDisconnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) {
    ...
  }
});
```

but in Netty 4 it's doesn't work. So, how I can handle this events now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check [New and noteworthy in 4.0](http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.0.html#wiki-h4-19) you can see that:

- In 3.x, When a new connected `Channel` is created at least three `ChannelStateEvents` are triggered: `channelOpen`, `channelBound`, and `channelConnected`. When a `Channel` is closed, at least 3 more: `channelDisconnected`, `channelUnbound`, and `channelClosed`.
- In 4.x, `channelOpen`, `channelBound`, and `channelConnected` have been merged to `channelActive`. Otherwise, `channelDisconnected`, `channelUnbound`, and `channelClosed` have been merged to `channelInactive`.

You should use the new API and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the new class to use in Netty 4 is `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`

```
pipeline.addLast("channelGroupHandler", new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {
  public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    ...
  }

  public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    ...
  }
});
```